# Compare an array explode with a string

Tags: php, string, compare, explode

I need some help for this problem. I have an array like this:

```
$asd = explode(",", "1, 5, 6, 8, 10");
```

I want to compare the $asd with a string:

```
if($asd == '8') {
    //something
} else {
    //something
}
```

I can't compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare array to string. You need to iterate array's elements. Like this:

```
foreach ($asd as $k)
{
    if ($k == '8') echo "ok";
}
```